# IdentityServer multi IDP configuration request

Tags: postman, identityserver3, kentor-authservices

How do I create a request that uses the Saml or Google IDP for authorization? My understanding is that if I put "acr_values=idp:Google" in my request then the request will be routed through my Google Idp path. Likewise if I put "acr_values=idp:saml2p" it should go through my Saml Idp. Is it a different path? Right now the request goes to localhost:98575/connect/token.

Here is my current Request:

```html
POST /connect/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:98575
Authorization: Basic  SomethingEncrypted
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: AGuid
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password&scope=customScope+openid+offline_access&username=actuallyfoobar@enterprisebeta.com&password=SomePassword&acr_values=idp:Google
```

Here is a snippet from my IdentityServer Starup.cs file:

```
public static void ConfigureIdentityProviders(IAppBuilder app, string signInAsType)

    {
        var authServicesOptions = new KentorAuthServicesAuthenticationOptions(false)
        {
            SPOptions = new SPOptions
            {
                EntityId = new EntityId("http://sp.example.com")
            },

            SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,
            AuthenticationType = "saml2p",
            Caption = "SAML2p",
        };

        authServicesOptions.IdentityProviders.Add(new IdentityProvider(
            new EntityId("http://stubidp.kentor.se/Metadata"),
            authServicesOptions.SPOptions)
        {
            LoadMetadata = true,
        });

        app.UseKentorAuthServicesAuthentication(authServicesOptions);

        var google = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Google",
            Caption = "Google",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,

            ClientId = "767400843187-8boio83mb57ruogr9af9ut09fkg56b27.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            ClientSecret = "5fWcBT0udKY7_b6E3gEiJlze"
        };
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(google);
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, can you edit the question to be a more clear on what the problem is and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: yes. Hopefully that clarified it. It was poorly phrased. Really it is an ignorant question. How do I make the request to hit my desired IDP? Is there some path configuration that I don't understand in IdentityServer or is it just to put the acr_values=idp:IDPName as specified in https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/identityProviders.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The acr_values with "idp:foo" is only used for the authorization endpoint, not the token endpoint. IOW, it's only used to automatically redirect the user in the browser to the indicated external identity provider.

Comment: Interesting. That would make sense why it didn't seem to matter for what I was doing. How does it determine the idp for Authentication? The scenario is that I don't want to present the user with multiple authentication buttons. I want to be able to programmatically determine which Idp to send them to based on information I have in my database. UserServiceBase maybe? Thank you for your help!

Comment: The value sent for the idp must match the auth schema for the registered external authentication middleware.